# Can SSTableSimpleUnsortedWriter be used on collection types or user-defined types?

Tags: cassandra, bulk-load

I understand that the new bulk-loader mentioned in [this](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/using-the-cassandra-bulk-loader-updated) blog post has a [problem](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8808) which prevents it from functioning as expected. As such, I am looking into using the SSTableSimpleUnsortedWriter. Does anyone know if it can handle set types and/or user-defined types?

If this question has already been answered else-where, I apologize. I looked but couldn't find an answer.

Thank you.